# transparent instead of solid grey models?

Tags: 3d-view

[image: description of pic]

I'm new to Blender, and I think I accidentally pressed something to turn everything into this transparent point only mode instead of solid grey models. Could someone explain how to change it back? Tysm in advance! Sorry if this question has been answered before, I just can't find it probably because I am describing the problem very badly.

Answer (score 0):

You may have clicked *transparency* in the viewport next to one of the four viewport shading spheres. To set transparency off, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. This will disable it.
You currently are in wireframe also, so click on the shader sphere next to wireframe if you want to go to a different view.